# Azure Devops Pipeline getting `default literal` error on Pipeline build

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I have a standard pipeline agent that works for CI whenever a pull request merged into master. It was working fine until I merged a pull request created by a visual-studio-2019 developed branch. Now I am getting

> error CS8107: Feature 'default literal' is not available in C# 7.0. Please use language version 7.1 or greater.

It is working fine when I push any changes with vs2017.

What should I do to avoid this error?

P.S: I want to keep using vs2019

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happen when you have code like the following:

`MyType foo = default; // assign the default value for this type`

In C# 7, the supported syntax is:

`MyType foo = default(MyType);`

but the simpler form was [added in 7.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/default-value-expressions#default-literal-and-type-inference).

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Don't use the newer form.  Change any existing instances of `default` to have a type, and change the settings so that the IDE will prefer the verbose form.  Here's a picture with the new form turned on, just change the Yes to a No:
   [image: Tools->Options setting for 'default' expression]
   If you're using .editorconfig files, you can configure the `csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression` setting.
2. Set the [language version for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) to be high enough to support the new syntax.  Keep in mind that if you set it to `latest` it *may* use a different version between your development box (VS2019) and your build agent (e.g. possibly still on VS2017).

Answer (score 10):

I just solved this issue by updating my Agent Pool in the build pipeline to use "Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019"

[image]